# Wrong localization used on 10.8, all good on 10.10

Tags: xcode, cocoa, localization, appkit, localizable.strings

I've got an app localized to **english** (*base localization, default*) and **german** (*strings files*).

When running on 10.10 all works as expected, i.e. when system language is set to german the UI is showing in german. Otherwise it's using the english resources.

Under 10.8 about half of my views (appears to be limited to one project in my workspace) are using the german resources no matter what!

Any ideas what could cause this?

I've triple checked the resources working as expected against the ones (roughly half of the `.xibs` in my app) always showing up in german under 10.8, no difference found so far.

However, the project exhibiting the weird behaviour is **referencing the projects containing the xibs** - wonder if that causes the issue.

Any hints much appreciated!

Comment: Did you use base localuzation as German in your nib but have the plist set wrong? Not even sure if base localization nibs work right pre 10.10

Comment: Nope, all english. Even played around with the `.plist` files in case some Xcode bug is screwing with me.  **Base localization** is available allright on Xcode 5

Comment: The ***Mountains*** sample from ADC requires Xcode 4.5 or later, OS X 10.8 or later for demonstrating Base Localization (introduced in Xcode 4.5)

Comment: Possibly any of the newer localized string macros? I honestly don't remember how new those are either. Might dig through release notes docs to see what was introduced when.

Comment: @uchuugaka Doesn't seem likely :-/  All plain `.xib` files that don't work. Just hit the 'localize' button in Xcode. Following "*Internationalization and Localization Guide*" to the letter. Sigh.

Comment: Hmm. So no strings files? You did separate xibs per locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW - after more playing around with localization settings and basically turning base localization on and off a bunch of times for the project in question at some point *all* referenced projects were **suddenly & magically using the correct localization**.

Most definitely sounds like an OS or Xcode bug at this point to me.